# How to avoid duplicate values in a ArrayList for ExpandableListview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm not sure whats wrong in this

```
 HashMap<String, List<String>> expd = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
   ArrayList<String> hello = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> hello1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String tt="root,root1";
   n=tt.split(",");
    for(i=0;i<=n.length-1;i++){
        if(n[i]!=null){
            //Db event listener
            hello = new ArrayList<String>();
            hello.add("test");
            hello.add("test1");
            expd.put(n[i],hello);


        }

    }

    List<String> tests = new ArrayList<String>(expd.keySet());
    ExpandableListAdapter news;
    news = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this,tests,expd);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(news);
```

so in this,test and test1 are getting added twice to root and root1,so it ends up root>test,test1,test,test1

Does anyone have any inputs to avoid this ??

Comment: Can you post whole method into which above is written?

Comment: @Mani,its written in OnCreate method

Comment: Can you share logs of expd.keyset() being printed on console, before passing to the CustomExpandableListAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[HashSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashSet.html)** instead of **ArrayList**.

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the
>   iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that
>   the order will remain constant over time.

**ArrayList** allow **duplicates** while **HashSet** **doesn't** allow **<s>duplicates</s>**.

```
HashSet <String> hello = new HashSet <String>();
```

**Example**

```
HashSet<String> hsetOBJ = new HashSet<String>();
    hsetOBJ.add("ONE");
    hsetOBJ.add("ONE");
    hsetOBJ.add("TWO");

   System.out.println(hsetOBJ);//[ONE, TWO]
```

You can try with

```
 HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> expd = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
   HashSet<String> hello = new HashSet<String>();
   HashSet<String> hello1 = new HashSet<String>();

   String tt="root,root1";
   n=tt.split(",");
    for(i=0;i<=n.length-1;i++){
        if(n[i]!=null){
            //Db event listener
            hello = new HashSet<String>();
            hello.add("test");
            hello.add("test1");
            expd.put(n[i],hello);


        }

    }

    List<String> tests = new ArrayList<String>(expd.keySet());
    ExpandableListAdapter news;
    news = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this,tests,expd); // Change your Parameter; Set HashSet on that class
    expandableListView.setAdapter(news);
```

Comment: it says cannot resolve contstructor at hashset at (expd.keySet())

Comment: @Sam `HashSet<HashSet> tests = new HashSet<String>(expd.keySet());`

Comment: @Sam `List<String> tests = new ArrayList<String>(expd.keySet());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> expd = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> hello1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String tt="root,root1";
   n=tt.split(",");
    for(i=0;i<=n.length-1;i++){
        if(n[i]!=null){
            //Db event listener
            ArrayList<String> hello = new ArrayList<String>();
            hello.add("test");
            hello.add("test1");
            expd.put(n[i],hello);


        }

    }

    List<String> tests = new ArrayList<String>(expd.keySet());
    ExpandableListAdapter news;
    news = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this,tests,expd);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(news);
```